# How does STM32 demo USB-DFU boot loader check if user code is loaded?

Tags: stm32, stm32-hal, stm32h7

STM32 HAL demo USB-DFU boot loader contains this code:

```
/* Test if user code is programmed starting from address 0x0800C000 */
if (((*(__IO uint32_t *) USBD_DFU_APP_DEFAULT_ADD) & 0x2FFC0000) == 0x20000000)
{
  /* Jump to user application */
  JumpAddress = *(__IO uint32_t *) (USBD_DFU_APP_DEFAULT_ADD + 4);
  JumpToApplication = (pFunction) JumpAddress;

  /* Initialize user application's Stack Pointer */
  __set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t *) USBD_DFU_APP_DEFAULT_ADD);
  JumpToApplication();
}
```

How does this predicate `((*(__IO uint32_t *) USBD_DFU_APP_DEFAULT_ADD) & 0x2FFC0000) == 0x20000000` determine whether or not user code is loaded on STM32H7A3 MPU?
What is this magic **0x2FFC0000** mask?

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple and a very bad way. It simply checks if at USBD_DFU_APP_DEFAULT_ADD address (where initial stack pointer value should be) the value AND-et with mask is equal to some value.

I personally always add the CRC32 at the end of the app to check if the app is there and if the app is **valid**.

> ... determine whether or not user code is loaded on STM32H7A3 MPU?

It does not have anything in common with MPU

Comment: It makes sense. Checking the pointer value does not seem sufficient. But even that simplistic approach ST demonstrates in CubeMX `STM32Cube_FW_H7_V1.9.0` package does not seem to be correct. I suspect this mask value is incorrect because the first MSB byte (that is, 4th byte since STM32 is little-endian) of my test apps seems to always be 0x24 and 0x2F & 0x24 != 0x20. In another words, this demo code probably has a bug.
The question: what this mask correct value should be and why?

Comment: Never mind, it is obvious. This sample code verifies if the app start address (stack top) is in RAM address space - between 0x20000000 and 0x2003FFFF (256k). For STM32H7A3 this is INCORRECT because "regular" RAM (not DTCRAM) starts at address 0x24000000 and is 1024k large.

Answer (score 1):

This sample code distributed with CubeMX `STM32Cube_FW_H7_V1.9.0` package initially verifies if the app start address (stack top) lies in RAM address space - between 0x20000000 and 0x2003FFFF (256k).
For STM32H7A3ZI MPU (e.g. Nucleo-H7A3ZI-Q) this is incorrect because "regular" RAM (not DTCRAM) starts at address 0x24000000 and is 1024k large. It seems that the correct check for this MPU should be: `if((stackAddr & 0x24E00000) == 0x24000000) ...`
Although I do not quite understand why for this MPU default stack address configured by CubeMX is 0x24100000 which is top RAM address + 1.